# Conditionally choosing a DataContext with structuremap

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, structuremap

I have set up a new MVC project, and I am using structuremap to handle my DI/IoC. I am using Entity Framework and caching repositories, with repository classes and the EF data context.

So, (simplified) I have an **IRepository** which is implemented by concretes - **CacheRepository** and **EFRepository**. **EFRepository** is dependent upon the **DataContext** (DbContext), and **CacheRepository** is dependent upon **IRepository** (as a persistent repository fallback), and **ICachingService** (so I can choose my cache provider), and then **IService** implemented by **Service** which is dependent upon a number of Repositories.

My issue is that my login database is different depending on which area of the site is logged into (e.g. admin has a separate login database - this is done for reasons I won't go into here). I have a base datacontext that contains all my user tables, and is inherited from the two main datacontexts; so depending on which area of the site the user tries to log into, dictates which database is checked for the details - so I either need to be able to choose the datacontext or the connectionstring depending on the controller.

Could somebody offer me some guidance as to how to achieve this conditional choice of datacontext/connectionstring based on the controller being instantiated with structuremap?

My IoC registry currently looks like this (referencing one of the datacontexts):

```
        For<BaseDataContext>().LifecycleIs<HttpContextLifecycle>()
        .Use(x => new AdminDataContext());

        //REPOSITORIES
        For<IDAL.Repositories.Users.IApplicationUserRepository>()
            .Use<DAL.Repositories.Users.EFApplicationUserRepository>();

        For<IDAL.Repositories.Users.IUserLoginAttemptRepository>()
            .Use<DAL.Repositories.Users.EFUserLoginAttemptRepository>();

        For<IDAL.Repositories.Users.IUserRoleRepository>()
            .Use<DAL.Repositories.Users.CacheRoleRepository>()
            .Ctor<IDAL.Repositories.Users.IUserRoleRepository>()
            .Is<DAL.Repositories.Users.EFUserRoleRepository>()
            .Ctor<IDAL.Caching.IGenericCachingService<Common.Objects.Data.Users.UserRole>>()
            .Is<DAL.Caching.HttpContextGenericCachingService<Common.Objects.Data.Users.UserRole>>();

        //SERVICES
        For<IBLL.Services.IUserService>()
            .Use<BLL.Services.UserService>();
```

Comment: @Javid_p84, so far no - any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: not really. I added a couple of dummy interfaces to get over it. It's interesting that there is no solution for that so far (Or at least we are not aware of).

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without seeing the bigger picture of your architecture, but you can probably do something like this (where SomeService represents your business logic layer):

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private ISomeService someService;

    public MyController(ISomeService someService){
        this.someService = someService;
    }
}

public class SomeService : ISomeService {
    private SomeContext context;

    public SomeService(SomeContext context){
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy here - just standard constructor injection. Having that business logic layer between your controller and Entity Framework is a good practice and gives you a place to inject the right DbContext(s) without your controller having to know about Entity Framework.

Comment: I already have a DI pattern with DbContext, Irepository and Iservice, using an IoC container - my issue is the datacontext passed to my repository can be different for the same service and repository depending on from which area in the system it is instantiated for. How does/can my IoC container make that decision? i.e. how can I make the controller/namespace etc a factor in the choice of the datacontext instantiation in my IoC registry?

Comment: You're probably barking up the wrong tree with the controller/namespace dictating it. The pattern I demonstrated should work fine - just add multiple contexts to the constructor (Context1 context1, Context2 context2, etc). Now if you're using a generic repository on top of that that can use different contexts, you should refactor your Repo so that it takes a generic type IRepository<C> where C : DbContext. Then to append what I already demonstrated here, instead of ISomeService, it would be ISomeService<YourContext>.